# When to use Slf4j & Log4j

Tags: log4j, slf4j

Could anybody clear the confusion here.

If we are using slf4j and printing a log then do we need to use log4j.

or in which situation we have to use slf4j and log4j.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slf4j is an API Log4j is an implementation. Slf4j is an abstraction layer for logging purposes which helps in preventing projects being dependent on  specific implementation. If you write in slf4j you can migrate to any other implementation easily (e.g java logging API). But there is always a need for implementation which means slf4j does not stand alone, rather it cooperates with log4j.